# A single table to keep reports for different type of information

Tags: database, database-design, reporting

I have many kind of information like 'messages', 'comments', 'articles', 'reviews', ... stored in different tables in my DB.

I would like to make a 'report' functionnality for each one of them but I don't want overload the DB and limit the amount of resulting work.

So I would like to know what would be a good DB design to keep all these user reports in only one DB.

Thanks in advance,
Sébastien

EDIT: By report, I mean report abuse like racism, violence, ... in messages or comments, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean you want to keep all these user reports (not in one DB but) using only one table or at least a small number of tables.

Possible solution:

Add a new `Information` table that will act as a supertype for the Message, Comment, Article, Review, etc. tables (which will be the subtypes):

```
Information
-----------
InformationId
PRIMARY KEY (InformationId)
```

Add a new column `InformationId` in `Message` table that is a `FOREIGN KEY` to `Information`:

```
Message
-------
MessageId                  --- no changes here
... other data             --- or here

InformationId                        --- one additional column

PRIMARY KEY (MessageId)    --- no changes here
...                        --- or here

UNIQUE KEY (InformationId)           --- so every message, article, comment 
FOREIGN KEY InformationId            --- or review can be identified
  REFERENCES Information (InformationId)
```

Do the same for all other "information" tables, like Comment, Article, Review, etc.

Then add a `Report` table:

```
Report
------
ReportId                     
InformationId              --- which message, article, etc is reported
ReporterId                 --- who reports it
ReportType                 --- what type of abuse it is (racist, etc.)
DateOfReport 
Explanation
PRIMARY KEY (ReportId)      
FOREIGN KEY InformationId
  REFERENCES Information (InformationId)
FOREIGN KEY ReporterId
  REFERENCES Person (PersonId)              --- the User table
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's what I was thinking about, but now, what if I want to select all the reported items and their related data ? I have to make a JOIN for each "information" tables ; isn't it too bad for performances ?

Comment: No, I don't think so. You will probably have a `UNION` of subqueries (all with `JOIN`s between the `Report` and each one of the subtype tbales). Or a query with a bunch of `LEFT` joins to the subtype tables.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Hi, I know it has been 10+ years. I bumped into the solution and has one question. What problem might arise if I directly use the ReportId as FK in all those content tables like articles, commnets etc.? Probably my question is about the benefit of the information table. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your database is relatively small I would just process the reports on-the-fly instead of persisting them in a DB.

If you still want to persist your reports in the DB and you absolutely need to keep it in one table only, I would serialize the report data in some format like XML or JSON and keep it in a big TEXT or BLOB field. So your table will have two columns: report_id and report_data.

Yes another option is to use some OLAP solution/reporting engine that will store your reports (or partial report data) and leave your normalized DB nice and clean.